# Dynamically set SVG Element Color using Dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using JavaScript to determine which element I will change the color of in my SVG object:

```
var subjectID = "foo";
```

I can manually implement:

```
foo.style.fill="red";
```

But how do I get something like:

```
subjectID.style.fill="red";
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try document.getElementById("id")?

Comment: writers block :)  Yup, that does it.  Thanks!